# Python Import Error with Supervisord

Tags: python, django, celery, python-import, supervisord

I'm using supervisord to run celery as a daemon, but it gives me error `ImportError: No module named tasks worker`. I can run it from shell without supervisord. My config file for supervisord is like:

```
[program:celery]
directory=/home/yongfengzhang/videomaker
environment=PYTHONPATH="/home/yongfengzhang/videomaker:/home/yongfengzhang/videomaker/videomaker:$PYTHONPATH",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="videomaker.settings"
;command=/home/yongfengzhang/Envs/videomake/bin/celery -A "tasks worker" --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=4
command=celery -A "tasks worker" --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=4
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1
user=yongfengzhang                  ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
stdout_logfile=/home/yongfengzhang/logs/celery/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/yongfengzhang/logs/celery/celery.err
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

So under `/home/yongfengzhang/videomaker` I have a `tasks.py` that defines the celery instance and task function (not shown here):

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='amqp://myuser:bloomsky@localhost:5672/myvhost')
```

When directly run celery in this folder (`~/videomaker`), everything is fine. The `Envs/videomake` is where my virtualenv is located. There is a `__init__.py` in the folder. Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what is wrong here. You cannot use double quotes to group your arguments. Do the following should work:

```
command=/home/yongfengzhang/Envs/videomake/bin/celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=4
```

The arguments `tasks worker` should not be in double quotes. Thanks.